# Sharing Qt libraries among Qt applications

Tags: qt, dll, assemblies

Our company ships 2 Qt applications, for now, using Qt5.6 but in some time there will be more (using newer Qt versions). So the problem is, how to make them work all together with different Qt versions? We won't be able to rebuild all Qt apps shipped before, especially if there will be plenty of them. I don't think it's a good idea to place all necessary Qt libraries with each app because the repository size will grow fast. And I think it's just not wise to have many Qt dlls of the same version at one place. As long as I know, .NET solve such problem of different versions with assemblies installer, but I don't think it can help me with Qt. So any ideas of how can I solve it would be highly appreciated. Thanks

UPD: The system is Windows

Comment: we had the same problem. first we had all dlls in one central directory, but it didnt work out well. now we ship every applicaiton with its own set of dlls (disk space does not matter, except on some wood system) and the dlls do not go into the repo

Comment: It could be the resolution for us if we had 2-5 apps, not more... But we have many demonstrative apps for our devices that are small and simple but have to be shipped along with devices according to standard, even if they wont be used much. So we can't afford to ship each such app with 50+ MB dll base.

Comment: you could bundle the demo apps into one package/directory. so it would all use the same binaries

Comment: Yes, I could do so for now, but in some time, when Qt version is changed, we'll need to rebuild all previous shipped apps and ship them again if this new app is delivered to old customer whose apps use older version of Qt... For now we have about couple hundreds of such apps written in C so you can imagine scope of disaster if we'd have to rebuild all these apps each month =)

Comment: i am confused ... you search for an answer because "Our company ships 2 Qt applications" and argue with "about couple hundreds of such apps written in C"

Comment: I'm sorry for such misunderstanding, we have such apps that I was talking about now written on C with CVI. There are many of such apps already (couple hundreds) but on Qt there are still 2, for now. But in some near future, if we continue using Qt for such apps, there will be nearly so many written on Qt as there are now written on C with CVI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually an answer is quite straightforward, you can ship one Qt version (binaries) as long as they are binary compatible. With each release Qt announce binary compatibility or non-compatibility, so if for whatever reasons you need to switch to newer version and ship new applications with newer not compatible version you might want to ship a new Qt DLL chain.. This can be achived differently (depends on how you layout you install), for example you can have a common lib dir with sub directories based on Qt version which you will extend. (of course you will need appropriate PATHS set then running different applications) :

app\
app\app01
app\app02
...
lib\
lib\Qt5.6.1
lib\Qt5.7.0

etc, then you will have (for example) to wrap your exe files to .bat like:

run.bat

SET PATH=....\lib\Qt5.6.1\
app01.exe

etc..

it's all depends on your install layout and goals